# Identifying element which has different namespace bindings

Tags: java, xpath

I have a xml which looks some thing like this.
Note: the ms-xrm namespace is mapped differently for the two AuthenticationPolicy elements.

```
<ms-xrm:AuthenticationPolicy xmlns:ms-xrm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services"> 
     <ms-xrm:Authentication>LiveId</ms-xrm:Authentication>
</ms-xrm:AuthenticationPolicy>

<ms-xrm:AuthenticationPolicy xmlns:ms-xrm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2012/Contracts/Services"> 
    <ms-xrm:Authentication>OnlineFederation</ms-xrm:Authentication>
</ms-xrm:AuthenticationPolicy>
```

I wanted an XPath that would give me precisely these elements, If I try

```
//ms-xrm:AuthenticationPolicy
```

I get both elements.  I tried

```
//AuthenticationPolicy[namespace-uri()='http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2012/Contracts/Services']
```

This gave me empty list. What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You say you want "precisely these elements", but then you imply that an expression that gives both elements is wrong, so I imagine that perhaps you only want the second.

The query

```
//ms-xrm:AuthenticationPolicy
```

should not give you both elements; it should give you one or the other depending how the namespace prefix ms-xrm is bound. In XPath, a namespace prefix can only be bound to one namespace. You haven't said what XPath API you are using, or how the namespace prefix gets bound, but it must refer to one of the two namespaces and that determines which element is selected. Namespace prefixes used in XPath have no relationship to prefixes in the source document (unless your API causes them to be initialized this way.) If what you are saying is right, this is a bug in your XPath processor.